Python: Why am I receiving a passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns is not allowed Error?
I am new to Python and am completing an assignment from Textbook: Healthcare analytics made simple: Techniques in healthcare computing using machine learning and python. opens in new window Packt Publishing, Limited.
Chapter 6: Measuring Healthcare Quality. Stuck on page 154.
I am receiving an error stating "
MergeError: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'State_x', 'City_x', 'Hospital Name_x', 'County Name_x', 'Address_x'} is not allowed.

Code:
    import pandas as pd 
    pathname = (
    r"C:\Users\rebec\OneDrive\Desktop\hos_revised_flatfiles_archive
    _10_2018\\"
    )
    files_of_interest = [
        'hvbp_tps_11_07_2017.csv',
        'hvbp_clinical_care_11_07_2017.csv',
        'hvbp_safety_11_07_2017.csv',
        'hvbp_efficiency_11_07_2017.csv',
        'hvbp_hcahps_11_07_2017.csv'
    ]
    dfs = {
        foi: pd.read_csv(pathname + foi, header = 0) for foi in 
    files_of_interest 

    for k, v in dfs.items():
        print(
            k + ' - Number of rows: ' + str(v.shape[0]) +
            ', Number of columns: ' + str(v.shape[1])
        )

    for v in dfs.values ():
        for column in v.columns:
            print(column)
            print('\n')

    df_master =dfs[files_of_interest[0]].merge(
        dfs[files_of_interest[1]],
        on='Provider Number',
        how='left',
        copy=False
    )
    print(df_master.shape)

    print(df_master.columns)

    for df in dfs.values():
         df.columns  = [col if col not in ['Provider_Number'] else 'Provider    
    Number'
                       for col in df.columns]
        for num in [2,3,4]:
            df_master = df_master.merge(
                dfs[files_of_interest[num]],
                on='Provider Number',
                how='left',
                copy=False)
            print(df_master.shape)

Error received:
    "MergeError: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns    
    {'State_x', 'City_x', 'Hospital Name_x', 'County Name_x', 'Address_x'}
    is not allowed."

I followed the instructions in the book directly and was not anticipating an error. Up until the last section of code, I had the same result as the book. I am new to coding in general and uncertain of where to start to try to resolve.
I will email the professor as well but figured it wouldn't hurt to post here.

Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message.

When you merge, columns that are not used as merging key, but are existing on both sides of the merge, get assigned a suffix to disambiguate:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'B': [1, 2]})

df1.merge(df2, on='A')

   A  B_x  B_y
0  a    1    1
1  b    2    2
2  a    3    1

In your case you might have performed successive merges, and one column that would be created already exist:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'B': [1, 2], 'B_y': [3, 4]})

df1.merge(df2, on='A')
# MergeError: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'B_y'} is not allowed.

Here B is present on both sides so B_x/B_y should be created, but B_y already exists, which triggers the error.
A workaround, if you can't change the merge logic, would be to use different suffixes:
df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=('_x1', '_x2'))

   A  B_x1  B_x2  B_y
0  a     1     1    3
1  b     2     2    4
2  a     3     1    3

Since you have a loop you could do something like:
for num in [2,3,4]:
    df_master = df_master.merge(
                dfs[files_of_interest[num]],
                on='Provider Number',
                how='left',
                copy=False,
                suffixes=(f'_x{num}', f'_y{num}')
                )

